# If Chebyshev's upper bound gives same value as the actual probability calculation, what can we conclude?

Tags: self-study, markov-process, probability-inequalities

As an example, if Chebyshev tells $P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)\leq 0.25$ and the actual probability for $k=2$ is also $0.25$.

Comment: It would suggest that you have the discrete distribution for $X$ that yields the Chebyshev bounds.

Comment: In the bottom third of the (long) page at http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/notes/class_06/properties.htm, I provide a graphical demonstration of Chebyshev's Theorem. It ought to make it immediately apparent where the probability must be concentrated when equality holds (thereby supporting @Glen_b's comment).  This is discussed under "Comments" at the very bottom.

Comment: @whuber Very interesting link.

Comment: @whuber I bookmarked the page to read in detail later :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a real number $\mu$ and a positive real number $\sigma$, consider a discrete random variable $X$ that takes on values $\mu$, $\mu+2\sigma$ and $\mu-2\sigma$ with probabilities $\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{8}$ and $\frac{1}{8}$ respectively. It is easy to verify that $E[X] = \mu$, $\operatorname{var}(X) = \sigma^2$. For this random variable,
$$P\{|X-\mu| \geq 2\sigma\} = P\{|X-\mu| = 2\sigma\} = 0.25$$
exactly.

More generally, for $a > 1$, a random variable $X$ that takes on values $\mu$, 
$\mu+a\sigma$ and $\mu-a\sigma$ with probabilities $\frac{a^2-1}{a^2}, \frac{1}{2a^2}$ and $\frac{1}{2a^2}$ respectively enjoys the property that $E[X] = \mu$, $\operatorname{var}(X) = \sigma^2$,
and for this random variable,
$$P\{|X-\mu| \geq a\sigma\} = P\{|X-\mu| = a\sigma\} = \frac{1}{a^2}$$
exactly.

This is a discrete distribution for which the Chebyshev inequality is
satisfied with equality (cf. @glen_b's comment).  Can you find other
solutions? For example, can you put smaller masses further away from 
the mean than $a\sigma$ so that the variance remains $\sigma^2$ and
Chebyshev's inequality is satisfied with equality at $a\sigma$? Why or why not?

Comment: Thank you for explanation!But can you explain how $$P\{|X-\mu| \geq a\sigma\} = P\{|X-\mu| = a\sigma\}$$. Are we saying that chebychev and exact probability are equal.

Comment: **For the random variables constructed in my answer,** $$P\{|X-\mu| \geq a\sigma\} = P\{|X-\mu| = a\sigma\} + P\{|X-\mu| > a\sigma\} = P\{|X-\mu| = a\sigma\} + 0 = P\{|X-\mu| = a\sigma\} = \frac{1}{a^2}.$$ Chebyshev's inequality says that $$P\{|X-\mu| \geq a\sigma\} \leq \frac{1}{a^2}.$$  As pointed out elsewhere, for _most_ random variables, the $\leq$ sign in Chebyshev's inequality can be replaced by $<$. The random variable $X$ described in my answer is one for which such a replacement is _not_ possible: Chebyshev's inequality _does_ apply, but _equality_ holds, the $=$ part of $\leq$.